# MySQL table from phpMyAdmin's tracking reports

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, audit

Using phpMyAdmin I can track a certain table's transactions (new inserts, deletes, etc), but is it possible to change or export it to a SQL table to be imported into my site using PHP.

Comment: what exactly do you want to export? i mean the transactions modify your table. so you can export the table (select db -> export -> Format: SQL) and import it on your website again using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Well I can do that but I need that to be done automatically and with every transaction, what I need to export is the Data definition (query) statement, date and user of every new transaction.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not exactly what I was looking for, I found a way to do it for the time being, one of the tables in the phpmyadmin (it's own) database is called pma__tracking, which contains a record of all tables being tracked, one of its columns is the data_sql longtext column which writes each report (ascendingly which is a bit annoying) in the following format

```
# log date username
data definition statement
```

Just added it for future references.